# Partial differential equation in $C^0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For $f \in C^0([0,1])$, I have the following partial differential equation:

$$u''(x) = f(x)$$ in $\Omega = (0,1)$
$$u'(0) = u'(1) = 0$$

Why is this equation not well posed in $H^1(\Omega)$?

--> Is it because of the missing boundary conditions?

Answer (score 4):

That problem can be interpreted in a *weak formulation*, that is, a *solution* to that equation is a $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that 
$$
\int_\Omega - u'\phi' =\int_{\Omega} f\phi,\qquad \forall \phi \in H^1(\Omega).$$
Thus, there are no regularity problems. The lack of well-posedness comes from a much more trivial issue; there is no uniqueness, because if $u$ is a solution, then so is $u+C$ for any constant $C\in\mathbb R$.

See [the book of Brezis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387709130), section 8.4.

Answer (score 3):

Set $v=u'$ then you are trying to solve the problem
$$
v'=f(x)\\
v(0)=v(1)=0
$$
But $$v(1)-v(0)=\int_0^1v'(s)\,ds=\int_0^1f(s)\,ds$$
so the equality of the boundary values is only possible if $f$ has mean zero.

In general you only get one boundary condition for a first-order ODE. As solutions, if any exist at all, are in $C^2$,
$$
u(t)=u(0)+\int_0^t(t-s)f(s)\,ds,
$$
the discussion of $H^1$ properties is a side-issue.

Comment: Good answer. You are right that a "weak formulation" is not really important since here the problem is 1-dimensional, so it can be recast as an integral equation.

Comment: I see how regularity is a non-issue since the solution will be in $C^2$ anyway. Deleted the silly answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! What if $f(x) = (x- \frac{1}{2})$ and $u(0) = 0$ --> what basis for a finite dimensional subspace $S \subset S^1_G := \{ \phi \in C^0([0,1]) | \forall r \in G: \phi|_r \in \mathbb P_1 \}$ would you choose to approximate the solution $u$ numerically?